# Xlib multi-touch support for existing application

Tags: ubuntu, multi-touch, xlib

I am trying to add multi-touch support to an existing Xlib application and would like some advice on how to approach this. I am not particularly familiar with the framework so I don’t know what the possibilities are but I had two approaches in mind.

**1.)**
Create a library that gets loaded by the main application to enable multi-touch. I thought an API could be designed to pass a window ID across and the library would do XSelectEvents with XI_TouchBegin, XI_TouchUpdate, XI_TouchEnd on that window.

However the issue I face here is the application already has its own event loop that I cannot modify so the only way I could imagine this working is if the library could somehow run its own event loop that does not interfere with the main one. I don’t know it this is completely impossible because there is only one queue per window and the main event loop will already be processing that queue.

**2.)**
Create a global whole screen touch handler that gets the touch events for the entire screen and decides to forward them on if they intersect with a widow within my application. 
The issue I face here is I don’t know how or if it is possible to write a whole screen touch listener.

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated, the main reason I am trying to handle touch in these unconventional ways is because I cannot access or modify the existing applications event loop for its various windows.